# Google sheets script and sending multiple emails?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I've searched everywhere on the web and on this site as well. What I want to do is relatively simple, however I don't know enough about javascript to write it myself but I am learning.

I have a google sheet with email addresses as well as data in 5 columns. Let's say there are 3 email addresses total. Now say there are 3 rows with the same email address and each row has new/different data than the previous row. I want to send JUST 1 email to that address with the 3 rows / 5 columns of data. There also may be an email address but with no data in the rows/columns. Obviously nothing should be sent from that row. Then there's the second email address. Repeat but send to the new email address. Next email, etc.

[Here's the sheet to give you a clearer picture.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Xg1cT3H5nlhSiJLzhc-V9U0bzRVGJ-_nbm20Swe1ak/edit?usp=sharing) I would like to keep the look/color of the table of column B through Column F in each email.

The following script had me most of the way there (sans the look/color of the table), however when I tried using it a few days ago it was sending a new email for each row of data instead of just one email for several rows of data...but it previously was working! (again sans the look/color of my sheet, it was simple text)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:m8");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Modified
  var temp = [];
  var emailAddress, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5;
  for (var i in data) {
    [emailAddress, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5] = data[i];
    var message = '\n\n' + data1 + ' ' + data2 + ' ' + data3 + ' ' + data4 + ' ' + data5;
    if (emailAddress || !data1) {
      if (temp.length > 0) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(temp[0], "Subject", temp.slice(1,temp.length).join("\n"));
        var temp = [];
      }
      temp.push(emailAddress, message);
      if (!dimension) break;
    } else {
      temp.push(message);
    }
  }
}
```

The format of the body of the email should look like the following, but again, I also want it to retain the look/feel/color from the sheet:

[image: screenshot of data/sheet in email]

Once that's working, I would like my email signature from Gmail included in the email. I'm not sure if I can get it exactly as is in my Gmail account, or just simple text via javascript.

I have this line but that's simple text. Any way to get my logo/formatting/etc. to match my Gmail or outlook account?

```
 var signature = "\n---\nsample signature";
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Tanaike  let me know what you think :) thank you.

Comment: **1)** [Don't use for-in with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) **2)** Make an object (`{}`) with email address as keys in the `for` loop on `data`, e.g. `{"person@domain.com":{"subject": subjectText, "body": bodyText, "mySig": mySigText}, "person2@example.com":{....}, ... }`. Then once you have built the object, iterate over it to send the emails: `for(var email in mailData) { /* use data in mailData[email] ... */ }` For HTML formatting: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

Comment: Appreciate that, @tehhowch I'm really not sure what to make of most of that so I'll keep reading.

Comment: @tehhowch - I have a list of 50 emails...each email has different data although each one uses the same columns. So say one email has 4 rows for of data, I need the script to send the 4 rows of data in that one email. I want to use the current code which was working without adding 50 different emails. So 4, 5 rows of data and one email. Right now it's sending an email for each row of data. Can we start there? What do I need to do?